# Java / Printing a LinkedList node containing an array

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList test = new LinkedList();
    int[] numberPair;
    numberPair = new int[2];
    numberPair[0] = 1; numberPair[1] = 2;

    test.add(numberPair);

}
```

How would I go about accessing the array in the first node of this list and printing it? I've tried all kinds of casting with test.getFirst(), but either it prints out the memory address or I get a long list of casting errors for objects.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Arrays.toString()`.

See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) for details.

Edit:

As other answers have pointed out, you should also use generics with your List. You should declare it as a `LinkedList<int[]>`. And then as you iterate over the elements, use `Arrays.toString` to convert each element into a string and print the result.

Comment: Thanks, all I needed to do was declare it with <int[]>, and Arrays.toString started working. I'm not sure why it would affect that, but, hey, it works.

Comment: @user1204458: Unless you use `<int[]>` (or explicitly cast the element into `int[]` after getting it from the list) it is considered to be an `Object`. You can't apply `Arrays.toString()` on an `Object` since it expects a `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

If using java 1.5+ use java generics like so:

```
LinkedList<int[]> test = new LinkedList<int[]>();
int[] top = test.getFirst();
for (int i: top){
   System.out.print(i+" ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a generic type instead of a raw type.

```
LinkedList<int[]> test = new LinkedList<int[]>();
```

When do `test.getFirst()`, you are getting an int array back, so just iterate through it.

```
int[] bla = test.getFirst();

for ( int i : bla )
    System.out.println(i);
```

Or use

```
Arrays.toString(test.getFirst());
```